# Crystal Reports Number Formatting

Tags: crystal-reports

I am working in Crystal Reports and trying to fulfill a formatting requirement on the result of a calculation.

I have yearly gross salary / 52 to get weekly salary.

{HRPERSNL.p_annual} / 52

Example result is 1254.75 I need to change that output to 00125475.

Comment: `totext({HRPERSNL.p_annual} / 52,'00000000')`

Comment: I tried that, this is the result I got.  with a value of $1254.75 it returned 00001254, dropping the .75 at the end

Comment: Then multiply by 100 to drop the decimals.